# GNU Radio, How to do BPSK Modulation and Demodulation using HackRF One?

Tags: gnuradio-companion

I can say I'm a beginner and inexperienced in communication. I'm using GnuRadio, and after software testing I'll try to test using HackRF One.

At first, I want to create a RF Signal, and send the signal as BPSK modulated signal(because I read somewhere that BPSK is better than other modulation modes, but I might be wrong), and then read the signal by using BPSK Demodulation.

Right now, I'm trying to do a BPSK Modulated RF Signal. And I want to test if I generate the signal correctly, so I think I'll need to do BPSK Modulation and Demodulation.

For example, I'll send "1010" data using RF Carrier Frequency as BPSK Modulated Signal, and then I'll demodulate the signal, and I should be reading "1010" data, right? Or how else I can test what I'm doing?

Long story short, what I mean is: I cannot be certain if I did the signal generation right or wrong, How can I be sure?

And here is my block diagram try: [BPSK Mod and Demod Block Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTDt6.png)

I'm very much lost, and if somebody can help I'd be appreciated.

PS: After doing this for one RF Frequency, I'll try to do a frequency sweep for example from 10 to 100 MHZ in steps of 5MHz.

Comment: all the blocks you used are buggy and hence have been in the "deprecated" category for multiple years. So, this won't work.

Comment: Please refer to the official [GNU Radio tutorial](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Tutorials) –  the last chapter is a PSK transceiver, but make sure you've read the other chapters first, because it'll not make much sense without.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks, i'll look and read